# Multiple siblings, place some in same row & fill extra space

Tags: css, flexbox

I have no control of the html. I have a parent with multiple children.Only some of them must be in the same row, while the rest of them stay unaffected and one of them must take up all the extra space. Content is auto generated and % is not an option.

Other options except inline to place on the same row to avoid the problem are welcome as well.

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
}

.same-row-child {
  background: green;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="other-child">A</div>
  <div class="same-row-child">B</div>
  <div class="same-row-child">C</div>
</div>
```

To sum up: Α in the first line unaffected.
 B+C in the same line with B taking up all the extra space.

Comment: okay, and what about 3 div on the same row ... is it the last to use the remaing space or is it to be shared with the other but not the first ? .. Your question needs clarification , inline-table, inline-block,inline-flex,inline-grid makes no difference for where it stands but will matter for the children it holds.

Comment: I've simplified it to 3 divs. 1 is the unrelated as hinted from the name. That should be unaffected & have it's own row. The other two should be merged in the same line, but one of them must take all the extra available space.

Comment: okay, what is the idea with inline-flex ?

Comment: To place it in the same line, then trying to grow it. I see two possible solutions. To change the way i place them in the same line or to find a way to grow the inline element.

Comment: You misunderstand the use of flex ;)  this is a tutorial/reminder quiet clear https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and if you do not want the parent to be a flex box, then float is the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the idea is to use flex, then it should be the parent the flex box:

> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
>
> `display:flex;` `display:inline-flex;` It enables a flex context for all its **direct children**.

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.other-child {
  width: 100%;
}

.same-row-child {
  background: green;
}

.parent :last-child {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="other-child">A</div>
  <div class="same-row-child">B</div>
  <div class="same-row-child">C</div>
</div>
```

*looks like not the option you would use* **See next option**

---

The oldish way is `float` and `overflow`, and the one to `float` is the one that **comes first** and is supposed to shrink on itself.

> see https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/
>
> Aside from the simple example of wrapping text around images, floats can be used to create entire web layouts.

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
}

.other-child {}

.same-row-child {
  float: left;
  background: green;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.parent :last-child {
  float: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="other-child">A</div>
  <div class="same-row-child">B</div>
  <div class="same-row-child">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Float literally does exactly what i need without affecting the parent. For whatever reason my brain tried to forget the pain of the float & only tried to solve it with modern solutions.Thanks for the complete answer & educating me, have a nice day.